# How to check which file systems are supported (and enabled) on my system to use with mount?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I've been reading the man page for `mount` as well as googling for an answer for some time now, with no success. I would like to check which file systems are supported for use with `mount` on my system. I think I used this few years ago, but just can't remember how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the man page of mount (`man 8 mount`) look for the explanation of option `-t, --types`. There you find all supported filesystems. That worked well for Linux for me.

It won't work for Mac but there you know the supported filesystems anyway.

**Update:** And a more dynamic way would be `$ cat /proc/filesystems`

**Update2:** To inspect all filesystem modules for the running kernel you can run `$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs`.

Comment: +1 for inspecting `/proc/filesystems`. Any insights into filesystems supported by (unloaded) kernel modules?

Comment: thx very much... actually, your updates were more useful to me :)... i know about types, but i wanted to know if there is a way to know which are 'active'

Comment: What about NTFS? It not shown on any of these lists but I am able to mount (although only read-only, but still)?

Comment: @MrCalvin that means you're using the [FUSE NTFS driver](https://superuser.com/q/579861/241386) (represented by `fuseblk` in `/proc/filesystems`). You should really avoid it and use the new [ntfs3](https://docs.kernel.org/6.1/filesystems/ntfs3.html) [kernel driver](https://www.phoronix.com/news/New-NTFS-Likely-For-Linux-5.15) instead