# Linux Fuse module - determine supported file systems

Tags: linux, filesystems, openwrt, fuse

Wondering how you can determine what filesystems are supported via FUSE on a Linux system? I ask as the performance of any NTFS formatted USB HDD I attach to my Netgear DGN2200v3 is painful and write access unreliable, so wanted to check what else is available. So thought I'd have a quick look to see what's supported by the modem. After a quick telnet it appears the kernel supports the following e.g.

```
# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   sockfs
nodev   usbfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   inotifyfs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
nodev   ramfs
        vfat
nodev   jffs2
nodev   fuse
        fuseblk
nodev   fusectl
#
```

Which implies the NTFS support is FUSE based, but am wondering how to find out what else is supported via FUSE e.g. UFS, HFS+.......

Just need some help to know what to grep / look for and possibly where on the Filesystem, to save me having to format USB sticks / HDDs in every FS known to Wikipedia and attach them to see what mounts.

I'm aware I could simply reformat a HDD to ext3 and hack any PC / Mac I latter directly attach the USB HDD to to support ext3, but if UFS is an option there's already native: Windows, OS X and Linux support. I'd like to avoid a 4GB file size limit so FAT isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By its very nature, FUSE is open-ended in which kinds of filesystems it supports. So there is no list. The point of FUSE is that any userspace software can come along and implement a filesystem.